# How to put Google Adsense in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, adsense

Do anyone know how to put Google adsense ads inside a GWT web application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the javascript-code from Adsense in the single HTML page that GWT starts with. This way the advertising will not be displayed in the same area as GTW but above/below the GWT code. For advertising that could be ok.

This example places a baner above the application:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>www.javaoracleblog.com</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.javaoracleblog.aggregator.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript"..
ADsense code here 
</script>
    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

In order to indicate to Google WT that the site of Google adsense can be trusted you need to add a regex matching URL to the -whitelist command line argument.

Note that this will probably not solve the problems desribed in the above "Why I dumped GWT" article.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread on AdSense](http://groups.google.com/group/adsense-help-troubleshooting/browse_thread/thread/632a7d4cf3d2e06/da4e75482cc5c027):

> Short version, you can't use Adsense
>   via Ajax without breaking the
>   programme policies/t&c's
>
> Long version...
>
> Ad code passed through an xmlhttp call
>   is not rendered, it's just treated as
>   text (hence, responseText).  The only
>   way to execute js code is to use
>   "responseXML" coupled with the
>   "exec()" command.
>
> For instance...
>
> If your xml contains something along
>   the lines of:
>
> This is the
>   content from the external
>   file javascript code
>   goes here
>
> You would assign a variable (called
>   page_data for instance) using
>   ajax_obj.responseXML, run the XML
>   through a parser and run
>
> exec(js variable or line from XML
>   here);
>
> Not really helpful from an Adsense
>   standpoint, but that's how it's done.

It's also worth mentioning [Why I dumped GWT](http://www.onthoo.com/blog/programming/2008/02/why-i-dumped-gwt.html):

> Another problem were my adsense
>   banners. Since I didn’t have a lot of
>   content on the page, the banners were
>   sometimes off topic. An even bigger
>   problem was that the banners stayed
>   the same when people searched for
>   different keywords (since the ajax
>   refresh didn’t trigger an adsense
>   refresh). I solved this by doing the
>   search with a page refresh instead of
>   an ajax call. The ajax part of the
>   site was limited to sorting, faceting,
>   i18n and displaying tips.

Comment: thanks, i really appreciate your, but i still need any workaround to make this work!

Comment: You realize by doing so you're violating the AdSense terms?

Answer (score 2):

You might check out the [interview](http://www.infoq.com/articles/progwt) I did with InfoQ. It includes a sample chapter from my book and it happens to be on SEO.

It's not trivial, but I think the solutions in the chapter let GWT work nicely in an environment where SEO is important. The basic solution is to implement something I call 'bootstrapping'. This means that your pages take the info that would normally come across in GWT-RPC requests and serialize them into the page. The GWT widget then loads this information without an RPC request. While your page serializes the info into JavaScript, it's easy to also write a <noscript> to the page that can be used for SEO.

Take a look at the PDF included here: [InfoQ GWT](http://www.infoq.com/articles/progwt) it goes into all the detail. The whole sample project is here: [google code](http://code.google.com/p/tocollege-net/) with source on github.

Comment: huh? The questions is about AdSense w/ GWT which is difficult because a standard GWT site wouldn't put much content on the page. The chapter explains an approach that puts content on the page so Google can crawl it to display relevant ads. Off topic?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want AdSense to be kinda "inside" GWT I'd use the Frame widget. Basically the Frame widget generates an <iframe ...> inside your GWT code. First I've thought iframe, UGH! But the <iframe> tag is still part of the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) and has been even extended by some attributes that seem to be there for exactly this "sandboxing" purpose. And with corresponding CSS styling you will not have any scrollbars around your <iframe>.

And here is the actual solution:

You should put

```
<ui:style>
    .sponsor {
    border: 0em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 6em;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Frame ui:field="sponsor" url="issue/extern/Google-AdSense.html" styleName="{style.sponsor}"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

into your [*.ui.xml*](http://code.google.com/p/loxal/source/browse/Lox/src/org/loxal/lox/service/issue/client/Header.ui.xml?spec=svnfc42cd1384513d9a394334b2d12fb4531a428db6&r=d4313215307c66c15cb0f155670d0a678e2ae3d1) file and the logic into the corresponding [.java](http://code.google.com/p/loxal/source/browse/Lox/src/org/loxal/lox/service/issue/client/Header.java?spec=svnfc42cd1384513d9a394334b2d12fb4531a428db6&r=d4313215307c66c15cb0f155670d0a678e2ae3d1) file:

```
@UiField
    Frame sponsor;
```

Also you should put the actual Google AdSense code (the <script> stuff) into a separate HTML file inside GWT's public folder which is - in this case - called *Google-AdSense.html* and is located inside the *extern* folder inside the *public* folder. **issue** (in the Frame *url* attribute) is in this case the GWT output folder.

And [here is how it looks like](http://lox.loxal.org): The ad in the upper right corner.

Btw this is also the way to embed the Google Analytics code into GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. I have a demo and source code here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/DemoGwtAdsene

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdSense and GWT together without using frames or other hacks if you take some care in how you create your host pages.

The key is to include your AdSense code in the host page and then to manipulate the dom element containing the ad but to **not detach** it from the page. So you can reposition the ads into the body of your other gwt code as long as the dom structure is not changed.

If you do detach and reattach the containing dom element then it will appear to work in Chrome   and Firefox but IE will show a blank space.  I tried initially to move the ads DIV element into a DockLayoutPanel and thought everything was great until I belatedly tested it in IE.

So this is OK:

```
Element element = Document.get().getElmentById("ad");
element.getStyle().setPosition(ABSOLUTE);
element.getStyle().setTop(20, PX);
```

But this is not:

```
myPanel.add(ElementWrapper.wrap(element));
```

because adding a widget to another widget re-parents it.

This means that you cannot use any of the built-in LayoutPanel stuff to hold your ad div because Layout cannot wrap an existing element (It creates its own DIV in its constructor).  You may be able to modify the layout panel stuff so it wraps an element and does not re-parent it... but I have not tried this yet.

I've tested the results in IE6+, Chrome and Firefox.  Downside is that you cannot refresh the ads unless you load a new page.  But in my case GWT was used to enhance html pages so that was not an issue.  In any case... are users more likely to click on a different ad than one they read several times?  Not sure it is so vital.

Answer (score 1):

I could do this using DFP Small Business + Async Publisher tag + AdSense integration:

Here is the code:

On  of your host page, put your publisher tag, something like:

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              var slot1 = googletag.defineUnit('/XXXX/ca-pub-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/transaction', [468, 60], 'div-gpt-ad-ZZZZZZZ-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
              googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
              googletag.enableServices();
            </script>

...
    </head>
```

I've created a view with uiBinder, with a div with the id specified at the head, like this:

```
    <g:HTMLPanel height="62px" width="100%">

            <div id='div-gpt-ad-ZZZZZZZ-0' style='width:470px; height:60px;'>
            </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

On the onLoad() method of the view, you initialize the ad, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLoad() {

    setupAd();
}

public static native void setupAd() /*-{
    $wnd.googletag.cmd.push(function() {$wnd.googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-ZZZZZZZ-0')});
}-*/;
```

To refresh the ad, just call refresh ad for the slot specified at head:

```
public static native void refreshAd() /*-{
    $wnd.googletag.pubads().refresh([$wnd.slot1]);
}-*/;
```

That's all!

For more information about the publisher tag, check:
http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649768

Now I'm struggling to know how to make AdSense bot to craw my ajax application. I've implemented the Ajax Crawling scheme:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

But I've got the information from AdSense forum that the AdSense bot (Mediapartners-Google) doesn't work with "escaped fragment" Ajax scheme. 
Does anybody know if Google plan to make any progress on that?

This limits this approach to serve just interest based ads, since the context based ad serving depends on ajax crawling scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Google's AdSense bot crawls your page to determine what ads to serve.  Therefore, you should not put AdSense on pages with mostly dynamic content.  It won't work well.

Maybe you should look into other ad programs?

Comment: Dynamic content IS what makes adsense relevant! The adsense script scans the site and determines which ads to display based on that content. On the other hand, GWT is pure javascript, and that's why adsense isn't working as it should, and not because the site is dynamic!