# Google Adsense in a GWT app

Tags: gwt, adsense

This post [How to put Google Adsense in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538674/how-to-put-google-adsense-in-gwt) is the best example of how to integrate Adsense into my app but I was wondered is there any google library available now ( 2 yrs later ) that makes the task easier?  I would have thought getting two google products Adsense and GWT to play together would be a lot easier?

Answer (score 0):

Google did not provide any official support on integrating Adsense in GWT. Perhaps, they might have reason for NOT doing so.